# All my react-native projects shows error TypeError: cb.apply is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm realtively new to react-native. All my projects were running fine in the morning, but somehow they stopped working. When I run react-native start and the react-native run-android, the app gets installed on the device but then this error props up which was not happening before.

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
 DELTA  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)/home/yehyaumar/Documents/dumm/busybee/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285
        if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments)
                   ^

TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
    at /home/yehyaumar/Documents/dumm/busybee/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:169:5)
```

I even cloned the repo from from scratch, but still the error persists. Please help out.
RN version: 0.59.2

My package.json file for one project,

```
{
  "name": "projectalpha",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.2",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-circle-checkbox": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-maps": "react-native-community/react-native-maps#master",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.12",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.6.0",
    "unstated": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ciao, this problem is connected to `graceful-fs` package. Plase, reinstall `graceful-fs`:

```
npm install graceful-fs --save-dev
```

And problem should be solved.

Comment: I don't have any direct dependency on graceful-fs. I tried to install graceful-fs as well, but still the same error.

Comment: Ciao, can you show me your project dependencies please? Thanks

Comment: I have edited the description and pasted my package.json file there. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ciao, seems that I'm repeting myself but I try to explain. Jest has a dependency with graceful-fs. Try to install graceful-fs as dependency like I wrote in my answer editated. Should solve

Comment: Thank you for your help. At the end, I had to clean everything including node, npm cache and clone again from the repo. But this library was required too, even though I tried to add it before as well but only worked when I cleared up everything.

Comment: Well done! I'm happy to ear that. These problems annoying you for hours and hours and when you solve you are so tired that you can't almost coding anymore. Now relax, a cup of coffee and then restart to coding :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 13):

For me, `npm cache clean —force` was not working, and graceful-fs is not direct dependency in my project.

```
OS: Ubuntu
Node: 14.6.0 
Npm: 6.14.7
```

I am still not sure why this error exits, but it works. I found this solution on [Flavio Copes's post](https://flaviocopes.com/cb-apply-not-a-function/).

open file `/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js`, where the error comes from.

Here’s the function that gives the problem:

```
function statFix (orig) {
  if (!orig) return orig
  // Older versions of Node erroneously returned signed integers for
  // uid + gid.
  return function (target, cb) {
    return orig.call(fs, target, function (er, stats) {
      if (!stats) return cb.apply(this, arguments)
      if (stats.uid < 0) stats.uid += 0x100000000
      if (stats.gid < 0) stats.gid += 0x100000000
      if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments)
    })
  }
}
```

comment out these lines (line 62-64):

```
// fs.stat = statFix(fs.stat)
// fs.fstat = statFix(fs.fstat)
// fs.lstat = statFix(fs.lstat)
```

Comment: This is a poor solution because it wouldn't work on a CI/CD system, for example, and every user that would download your project would have to change this to build the project. It's better to strive for builds with dependencies that works together.

Comment: FWIW, This seems to be the only solution that works for me. All instance of graceful-fs are at 4.2.10, which should suffice. I've force-cleaned the cache multiple times, changed versions of Node (though using older versions of Node is not an option), and tried deleting and re-installing the node_modules each time. You're right this is not a commitible solution. However it works well if you need it for a one-shot fix (in my case, it's for running ember-update-cli --run-code-mods)

Answer (score 10):

I've run into this problem while trying to start a react-native development server on one of my old projects - (React Native version 0.59.x). For me, the fix was downgrading the node version from `14` to `10` using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: This worked for me as well, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Go to C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
Delete npm and npm-cache

Try running again if it gives the error again uninstall and delete Nodejs completely, check that those two files above are still nonexistent and then redownload Nodejs.

On one of my computers the first way worked no problems the second one needed to have Nodejs completely replaced and then worked.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. I had to clean up everything like you suggested but it also required that I install graceful-fs library. Only then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for it.

Option 1:
Follow this directory
C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
Delete the npm folder and if there is one mom cache folder.
Run npm clean cache —force ( — force is now required to clean cache)
You should be good now if not do option 2.

Option 2:
Follow this directory
C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
Delete the npm folder and if there is one mom cache folder.
Run npm clean cache —force ( — force is now required to clean cache)
Make sure everything to do with Nodejs is deleted and uninstalled.
Reinstall Nodejs.
You should be good now

Comment: option 2: worked.  I used the default node+npm that came with Nodist.  And I am running npm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use node 12.3.1 and npm 6.9.0 to fix this error

```
nvm use 12.3.1
```

This installed both. `npm install` working again.