# TypeError: cb.apply is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm trying to run an existing React Native project that uses Metro Bundler. My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 and I've tried to run the app both on a physical Android device and on an Android simulator that I created with Android Studio.

I have successfully cloned the project's repo, installed its dependencies (`yarn`), built the app (`react-native run-android`), and opened the app on my phone and simulator. However, running `react-native start` errors out saying `TypeError: cb.apply is not a function`. Here is the full information and errors I get when running `react-native start`:

```
$ react-native start
warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - rn-fetch-blob: https://npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - rn-fetch-blob: https://npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
Looking for JS files in
   /home/ggiuffre/Documents/squib/app 

Loading dependency graph, done.
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)/home/ggiuffre/Documents/squib/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285
        if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments)
                   ^

TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
    at /home/ggiuffre/Documents/squib/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:169:5)
```

Installing `graceful-fs` (as recommended by [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63054816/3272066) about the same problem) doesn't change anything, and I still get the same error.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I had a very similar problem on CI, but it works normally on my local machine (Node 13). In the CI, when building the project on CircleCI or on AppCenter with a code that I already released two months ago it throws the error below. It just does not make sense, it's like node had broken dynamically.

I tested the same code with node 10, 12 and 14, but now it works just with node 10 (10.22.0).

The error I had:

```
/home/circleci/my-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285
        if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments)
                   ^

TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
    at /home/circleci/my-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:169:5)

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**UPDATE**

What solved my problem was to add a resolution to the `package.json` to do not allow any lib to use a version of graceful-fs that is before "4.2.4". Now it works again with node 12.

PS: Don't forget to run `yarn` or `npm run install` to update your `.lock`. If this solution does not work for you, please add a comment to this [thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34529) related to this problem on Node 12.18.3

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "4.2.4"
  },
```

Comment: OMG I love this answer, your update saved me. Been trying to fix the problem for hours now, tried every other solution available on the web and nothing was working. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

I got this too today when doing a build. (running node 12.8.3)

I reinstalled the follow package:

```
npm install graceful-fs --save-dev
```

This solved the above problem.

Answer (score 16):

An Ubuntu 20.04 user here with node 16.0.0. I was getting the same error when I would run:

```
> npx create-react-app [my app]
```

I found that I had to reinstall create-react-app (remove it from node_modules first) to solve it.

```
> npm install create-react-app
```

Comment: Ahwww yesss, thank you for sharing this. I did not have it installed, and instead of complaining that the module didn't exist, it was instead showing the error from the question. Maybe you should have it --save-dev as it is not a needed dependency for production?

Comment: Solved my different but related problem, ty for posting.

Answer (score 14):

I solved it on both my computers. One needed more work on it.

- Option 1:

  - Follow this directory `C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming`
  - Delete the **npm** folder
  - and if there is one **npm cache** folder. Run `npm clean cache -force`, or `npm cache clean -force` on windows ( — force is now required to clean cache)
  - You should be good now if not do option 2.
- Option 2:

  - Follow this directory `C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming`
  - Delete the **npm** folder
  - and if there is one **npm cache** folder. Run `npm clean cache -force` on linux, or `npm cache clean` on windows ( — force is now required to clean cache)
  - Make sure everything to do with Nodejs is deleted
  - and uninstalled NodeJS.
  - Reinstall Nodejs.
  - You should be good now.

Comment: i have follow your both steps but problem is still same

Answer (score 10):

If you have nvm installed, its even simpler. To check this, run

```
nvm --version
```

then to install the latest lts version of node, run

```
nvm install --lts
```

That's what worked for me, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows 10, I solved this issue by doing the followings:

First, this was the error:

[image]

1. Navigate to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\`
2. Remove any cache that may be there by typing `Run npm clean cache —force`
3. Remove the `NPM` Folder
4. Re-install the Node.js and make sure to include NPM during the installation of Node.js

After the above steps, I am able to run the npm like before and add modules that I needed.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:

1. Goto the path
   C:/Users/{User}/AppData/Roaming
2. delete the 2 folders
   **npm
   npm-cache**
   at path
3. npm clean cache —force

Comment: The third step is : npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to use `Husky` and this error occurs:

```
husky > commit-msg (node v15.6.0)
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2021-01-24T06_04_04_218Z-debug.log

>>> Installation [ 'commitlint@latest' ] fail with code 1 <<<

husky > commit-msg hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

I run the command below and problem was solved

```
npm i -D commitlint
```

Answer (score 1):

Your node version is not matching with the libraries/frameworks you are trying to use.
Try to update you node version and check.

Better to use nodist/nvm to do upgrade or downgrade with finger snap.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments)
                   ^

TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
    at /home/circleci/my-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20
```

For this in pollyfills.js file go to line 62,63,64 and comment those shown below, Worked for me for my Gitbook

```
 // fs.stat = statFix(fs.stat)
  // fs.fstat = statFix(fs.fstat)
  // fs.lstat = statFix(fs.lstat)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occuring because of new npm naming restrictions.  Project names can no longer contain capital letters.  Rename the directory with lower case letters.