# Windows_NT 10.0.18363

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

While solving the issues to run story book in my create reat app, I have changed the version of my npm to `3.10.10`. Then after that, while trying to run npm like `npm run start`, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18363
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm"
> npm ERR! node v12.18.3
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
> npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     E:\Career_Assistant_Project\react-server\npm-debug.log
> ```

Now I am not able to run my code. Can anyone help me figure out this issue?

Comment: Run `npm install -g npm` and see if it works

Comment: no use. the problem remains same

Comment: How did you change version of npm?

Comment: npm i -g npm@3. I have followed the advices in this link to make storybook workout in react. https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/145. but did work.

Comment: The issue was closed in 2016, it could be an outdated solution

Comment: I am able to solve the issue with the help of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214997/typeerror-cb-apply-is-not-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cb.apply is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214997/typeerror-cb-apply-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that describes the question". The current title doesn't describe much except what OS you're running.