# why I can not update npm in linux?

Tags: node.js, npm, vps

I ve been updating my npm, but every time I use `npm` command, it always goes wrong like

```sh
npm ERR! Linux xxx
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "outdated" "-g"
npm ERR! node v14.17.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
```

I ve tried reinstalled nodejs many times, but no use, what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cb.apply is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214997/typeerror-cb-apply-is-not-a-function)

Comment: my solution is find all directories relates to node, delete them all, then `apt remove nodjs` and reinstall it, then run npm to update, but this cause you should reinstall your npm global packages you installed before