# React Native setup Mac M1 (Air)

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, apple-m1

I follow this guy's tutorial
https://youtu.be/MJEcookWYUI?t=686

I get errors after the command on the video

```
admin@MacBook-Air:~/Demo$ npm run ios
npm ERR! missing script: ios   
npm  ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2022-09-12T22_06_04_217Z-debug.log
```

I searched many websites , tried to do everything i saw but i nothing worked.

**Please help**

Comment: Is 'ios' a dependency (did you install it?) or is it a script (did you add it to your package.json?)

Comment: Did you try running react-native run-ios?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
  }
```

Add this to `package.json` file in case it isn't there.
after adding run `npx react-native run-ios`

Comment: before adding this to  .json i run the npx react-native run-ios and i had error. (see comment above" .. So i added it and i run it and now i  get  "  error: unknown command 'run-ios' "

Comment: npm install --save react-native@latest

Comment: or try to run react-native run-ios

Comment: are you using expo or react-cli ? How did you created your project ?

Comment: i think i used react-cli . i followed  the tutorial of the guy's on youtube. also run react-native run ios doesnt work ........ would be that easy for you if we can talk via a chat app so you help me out?

Comment: npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2 create project and then npx react-native run-ios. This should work

Comment: $npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2 
and the results

✖ Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.68.2
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2022-09-13T11_06_19_276Z-debug.log

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/63256830/6654562

Answer (score 0):

check on your package.json script:

```
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
```

and try to running with `npx react-native run-ios` or `yarn ios`

Comment: I run the command "npx react-native run ios" and i get  .. error iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?.

Comment: did u install correctly? check the folder ios in root project is existing or not. try to upgrade the react native project with "npx react-native upgrade" in your root project directory

Comment: $cd myproject 
$npx react-native upgrade
$error Command failed: npm info react-native version
$npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63256830/6654562